# ¿Cuántas posiciones ocupa una variable COMP en un fichero secuencial? - COBOL

Tags: cobol

Alguien sabría decirme cuántas posiciones ocuparían las siguientes variables en un fichero secuencial:

```
02  VAR1     PIC 9(5) COMP.
02  VAR2     PIC 9(6) COMP.
```

Gracias. Un saludo.

Comment: [Este enlace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_8.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.mfjob.dev.doc/topics/r_dmnjbref_Storage_Lengths.html) puede serte de utilidad.

Comment: Gracias. Muy útil.

Answer (score 1):

Según [este link](http://www.simotime.com/databn01.htm) que describe el formato `Binary` o `Comp` de COBOL, depende de la plataforma, puediento ocupar 3 (IBM) o 4 (Micro Focus) bytes.

Como nota al margen, también tené en cuenta que al persistir el dato en un fichero, y también dependiendo de la plataforma, puede estar con los bytes más pesados al inicio o al final (Big Endian vs Little Endian).

Comment: Puede ser "packed binary" tambien.